# How to create archive in xcode with no sound null safety

Tags: xcode, archive, dart-null-safety

I have flutter project while creating archive in xcode getting below error

"Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:flutter_call_kit
- package:bringtoforeground
- package:flutter_voip_push_notification
  For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
  ../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/grouped_list-4.2.0/lib/grouped_list.dart:264:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.
- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {"

I have to upload app on testflight can i run with no sound null safety args in xcode

please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the project in Xcode:

1- Right click on `ios` folder > `Flutter` > `Open iOS module in Xcode`

2- Now from Xcode, go to `Build Settings`, then scroll all the way down, then expand the `User-Defined`. Now from the `Editor` menu > `Add Build Setting` > `Add User-Define Setting`:
[image]

3- Enter the key `EXTRA_FRONT_END_OPTIONS`

4- Enter the value `--no-sound-null-safety`

[image]

5- Build and enjoy, that's it!